# SQL Change Data Capture get all tables

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I need to audit data in all tables in database. I use SQL Server 2016. I enabled  Change Data Capture for all tables.

How to get changes from all tables chronologically?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Change Data Capture creates system tables in [cdc] schema to capture change events for each table. something like cdc.[TableSchemaName]_[TableName]_CT, this table will have all the changes done to your actual table in the chronological order. It is basically the data read from DB's transaction log file.

Another point - you need to query Maximum Lsn for the database at any point of time and also the minimum LSN for the table for which you want to read change data. The records between min and max LSN should give you the total changes for a table.

Reference link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-all-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql

Comment: Can I query all CDC tables in one call? I have 100+ tables so I dont want UNION.

Comment: CDC does not have any such procedure/function , by default, to read all tables data together. You will need to write custom SQL to make it happen